# When to use position absolute vs position relative when vertically aligning with css

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

Originally I followed this article which used `position: relative` on the child element: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpWKWg

But I couldn't get it to work on my code for the life of me:

http://jsfiddle.net/ge77ma0e/

---

Then I found these instructions which use `position: absolute` on the child element: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#vertical-block-unknown

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lpema

And when I tried it on my code it finally worked:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2ajtmks/

Any good explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss `display: block;` on `.valign`. The transform element as it seems should be applied to a block element, not inline. Here is the documentation:

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1 - Terminology - Transformable Element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level) or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform.

Also if you need to center only verticaly (and not horizontaly), change you `transform`s to:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: In the first article it is `.parent{display:block} .child{position:relative}` but when I tried the same structure in my code it didn't work. What finally worked in my code was `.parent{display:block} .child{position:absolute}`. The `translate` and `translatey` properties are synonymous in this example.

Comment: @user27068, The text is in a `p` element which already has `display: block;`

Comment: Ah ha, that makes sense now. I was mislead by the article stating the code as such `.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}`

Comment: This saved my life, however how will you do when you have multiple elements next to each other? I mean a div containing multiple anchor tags,

Answer (score 1):

By default, all elements on DOM are `position:static`. Properties like `top, left, right, bottom` aren't usable with a statically positioned element. Using any other positioning context like `relative` `absolute` or `fixed` allow you to use these values.

The method used in the solution is to push an element from top by `50%` and then pulling it upwards by half the `height` of the element. This is where `transform` comes into play.

Now, you can see that both of your articles use a different positioning context other than `static`. In first, it uses 'relative' and in the css-tricks example you see `absolute`.

The reason why your code isn't working because `transform` works on block-level elements but your text is inside a `span`. Add a `display:block` to it and you should be good to go.

I also noticed that you have `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` which should just be `translateY(-50%)` to compensate for the height of any box you are trying to vertically center by pushing it from `top` by `50%`.

Comment: This is very helpful as well, here is the updated code with `display: block` added to the child element: http://jsfiddle.net/ge77ma0e/2/