# Vertically centering, absolute position, multiple elements

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I'm using the following approach to vertically center an element with unknown height in a div with unknown height.

http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

The elements that I'm centering are anchor tags, so this answer solves the position relative issue.

[When to use position absolute vs position relative when vertically aligning with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587090/when-to-use-position-absolute-vs-position-relative-when-vertically-aligning-with)

However since I have one element next to the other, they overlap when using `position:absolute`

Is there any way that I can solve this? (I cannot use flexbox)

**HTML**:

```
<div class"parent-container">
  <a href="">Some content</a>
  <a href=""><img src""></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent-container {
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parent-container a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: But the obvious answer is to wrap the two links in a div and vertically center **that**.

Comment: There is the code, seemed unnecessary since everything was in the link, the actual question that I've pointed contains no code

Comment: What if I can't modify the layout?

Comment: If the link goes away, the question becomes useless. That's why we need to the code **in the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the children inline-block and use `vertical-align:middle`. No need for positioning.

```css
a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent-container {
  text-align: center;
  background:palegoldenrod
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <a href="">Some content</a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100">
  </a>
</div>
```

If the containing parent is taller than the content you can use a pseudo-element.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.parent-container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  background: pink;
}
.parent-container::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
  /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <a href="">Some content</a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot have a fixed height.

Comment: I'm not saying you have to. The height is to show that the vertical centering works **whatever** the height is - https://jsfiddle.net/33obkxh8/

Comment: Although your code works, there must be something else in my project that is preventing this from working. anyway thanks